# Angular - Jasmine/karma - subscribe lambda expression is not getting executed

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a Unit test case for an observable in angular 6 component using Jasmine/karma. Please find the component method for which I'm writing the test case.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
{
   this.editOrderContainer.getEditOrderState().subscribe(editOrderState => {
            this.shipAddressEditted = editOrderState.data.shipAddressEdited;
            this.shipInstructionEditted = editOrderState.data.shipInstructionEditted;
            this.hasShippingDetailsChanged = (this.shipAddressEditted || this.shipInstructionEditted) && this.existedAffectedOrderNumbers;
        });
...
}
```

In the above code, my test case should cover/expect for the variable  "hasShippingDetailsChanged". In spec file I would have the "it" as below

```
it('verify if Shipping instructions text is set to true if instructions test is changed.', () => {
            expect(component.hasShippingDetailsChanged).toBeTruthy();
        });
```

The code for mocking/spy in the .spec file is as below,

```
let editOrderContainer: any;
let getEditOrderState: any;

beforeEach(async () => {
...
     editOrderContainer = jasmine.createSpyObj('editOrderContainer', ['getEditOrderState', 'rebookOrder']);
            editOrderContainer.getEditOrderState.and.callFake(() => {
                return getEditOrderState;
            });
            getEditOrderState = {
                subscribe: function () {
                    return getOrderDetailsServiceResult();
                }
            };
            spyOn(getEditOrderState, 'subscribe').and.callThrough();
            ...
 });

 function getOrderDetailsServiceResult() {
        return {
            shipAddressEditted: true,
            shipInstructionEditted : true
        };
    }
```

The EditOrderContainer code is as below:

```
public getEditOrderState(): Observable<EditOrderState> {
        return this.store.select(s => s.editOrderReducer);
    }
```

The problem I'm facing here, **it is returing the values for editOrderState in the subscribe and the lambda expression statements are not getting executed**

i.e. the assignment statements for **shipAddressEditted, shipInstructionEditted, hasShippingDetailsChanged** are not getting executed.
I want these lines to be executed so that the required variable hasShippingDetailsChanged to be assigned.

Any ideas what is the mistake I'm doing here? why the subscribe lambda expression is not getting executed within the spec file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, the issue was in the way I created the spy for the editOrderContainer and its method getEditOrderState which returns an observable.

in my earlier code `Observable.of(editOrderState)` was missing which is required. also I shouldn't or need not mock/spy for the `subscribe` method

my spy object looks like below..

```
editOrderContainer = jasmine.createSpyObj('editOrderContainer', ['getEditOrderState', 'rebookOrder']);
editOrderContainer.getEditOrderState.and.callFake(() => {
            var editOrderState = getOrderDetailsServiceResult();
            return Observable.of(editOrderState);
        });


 function getOrderDetailsServiceResult() {
        return {
                data: {
                        shipAddressEdited: true,
                        shipInstructionEditted: true
                    }
                };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `stub` so that it can be reused at other places as well. Try below changes:

1. Make the `editOrderContainer` as `public` in constructor:

```
constructor(public editOrderContainer: EditOrderContainer,.....)
```

2. Create a `stub` as `EditOrderContainerStub`:

```
export class EditOrderContainerStub{
   getEditOrderState(){
     return of({
       data: {
          shipAddressEditted: true,
          shipInstructionEditted : true
        }
     })
   }
}
```

3. In `providers` of `spec` file :

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    providers:[{provide: EditOrderContainer , useClass: EditOrderContainerStub}],

//....... your declaration

});

it('verify if Shipping instructions text is set to true if instructions test is changed.', () => {
     component.existedAffectedOrderNumbers = true;
     component.ngOnInit();
     expect(component.hasShippingDetailsChanged).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

Comment: no, it didn't resolved the issue. still it is not getting executed even after doing the changes given by you

Comment: @Krishnan : Have you set `component.existedAffectedOrderNumbers = true` ? let me update my code